# MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE Некорректно перемещает мышь

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Мне нужно программно нажать на ЛКМ в 1160, 800; Координаты я получил через свое приложение через Cursor.Position на C#. Я пишу их в dx и dy, но оно перемещает их в левых верхний угол. Как я понял, Mouse_Move использует какие то особенные координаты и монитор состоит из 65355. Как мне перевести курсор 1160, 800? Если важно, у меня два монитора и основной 1920x1080

```
void Launcher() {
INPUT Inputs[3] = { 0 };

Inputs[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
Inputs[0].mi.dx = 1160; // desired X coordinate
Inputs[0].mi.dy = 800; // desired X coordinate
Inputs[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;

Inputs[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
Inputs[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;

Inputs[2].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
Inputs[2].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

SendInput(3, Inputs, sizeof(INPUT));

std::cout << "Играть\n\n";

}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    Sleep(5000);
    Launcher(); 
    Sleep(5000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Просто вычислить:
dx *= 65535 / width; dy *= 65535 / height;
где width и height - разрешение экрана.

Comment: @t3f Спасибо, работает